# Looking for a Vampire movie based on a scene I remember

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

More than 10 years ago, I watched a vampire movie on a French TV channel and I have been searching for its title for 2 years now. I believe it is not a famous movie since I was not able to find anything.

There was a scene where the main hero (I think he was a vampire hunter, at least he was killing vampires in the movie, badass style), transfused the blood of a vampire to reduce his heartbeat and avoid being detected by other vampires, to be able to access their nest.

The final scene of the movie shows the hero driving and putting sunglasses as the rays of the sunrise were bothering him.

The scenes are blurred in my mind as it is just a childhood memory, for me now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds a bit like [Vampires: Los Muertos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampires:_Los_Muertos). The hero, Jon Bon Jovi, receives a transfusion of vampire blood, I think to make him strong enough to fight the big bad (although could be for the reason given, I can't remember).

The finals scene shows him putting on his sunglasses as he drives off, as described.

Comment: yep. I was thinking the same thing when I just read the question.  that was the movie that popped in my head.  you got it up here about 10 minutes before me

Comment: It is the one. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Could this be the first **Blade** (Wesley Snipes) installment?

There is some transfusion mentioned, but only with a serum to protect Blade from succumbing to full-fledged vampirism.

Comment: Hi Buer! First, thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately, It is not Blade, I just check, right now. :(

Comment: Mine shouldn't be the accepted answer then

Comment: @fastblast:
You can remove acceptance by clicking on the checkmark again, or by accepting another answer by clicking on its checkmark.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks for the tip. As you guessed it, I am new to the platform :)